# React Native What Design Pattern should I be using for this calling API then updating other components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let's say I do an api fetching in the componentDidMount() in the App.js to get data for other components, for instance the data could be a ***List***. If I navigate to another component, and there is new data present for the list - how would I update this list so that it affects the other components, and if I'm at one of the other components how would I Re-render() the UI for that component?

How would the App.js do the API calls since I'm no longer in that activity (currently in the other component)?

I am not too sure what relevant libraries or patterns I should be using? Should I be using a singleton if I want all components to have access to this ***List***?

Comment: I would suggest redux

Comment: I'd go with singleton and RxJS. So the List will emit new values, and any component that needs to hear for new values, would subscribe to this List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a State Management Tool (eg. Redux, MobX).

Using this tool, the state of your application is kept in a store, and each component can access any state that it needs from this store.

The way Redux works is simple. There is a central store that holds the entire state of the application. Each component can access the stored state without having to send down props from one component to another.

Comment: If I were to use Redux, would I still need to do my API calls in the componentDidMount() in the App.js? Or is it possible to have api calls any component in case I need to re-render? Also if a state changes with redux how would I re-render a UI?

Comment: The redux has function called 'connect' that generates a wrapper component that subscribes to the redux's 'store'. When an 'action' (eg. "hey redux, change this data") is dispatched, the wrapper component's callback is notified. It then runs your mapState function, and shallow-compares, then re-render the component's UI.